# Why was one question not constructive but a dupe is protected?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

Notice that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php) is protected, whereas it is an exact dupe of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710062/php-what-is-wrong-with-mysql) that was closed as not constructive? Note that I don't care about the lost rep points (I freely put bounties on other peoples' questions) but rather I want to know how I could improve my questions in the future.

Comment: It is protected against noisy comments like "Thanks". That's all.

Comment: You also didn't lose any rep.

Comment: One tip: Don't make your question sound like it's seemingly trying to discuss a specific chat room. Just focus on the questions. The chat room info is fluff.

Comment: Another tip: Don't use tags in your titles...

Comment: Keep in mind that if your question wasn't closed as not constructive, (or if it was reopened) it would just be closed again as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is asking about "some people [who] discussed avoiding the mysql_* functions," which probably sounded as subjective to who read it. In fact, one of the comments says, "You can ask them - just @ one of them."
Referring to a chat discussion probably didn't help with how the question was perceived; if you referred to the warning put in the PHP documentation, the question could have interpreted differently.

The other question's purpose is creating a canonical question for something that is (I assume) continuously suggested to who asks a question about PHP code using the old MYSQL functions. I think the fact that is explicitly said in the question helped in perceiving it differently.

As side note, a protected question can still get votes to close it, and be closed; locked questions are the ones that cannot be closed. The only purpose of protecting the question is avoiding users with a reputation lower than 10 (who are responsible of spam/thanks posts) write an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from better formatting, there isn't much difference between your question and the recent one from October. One main difference is you mentioned chat, whereas Madara just came out and asked, which leads to less noise.

I don't think your question is any better or any worse than Madara's, but I suspect mentioning chat caused a distraction and caused everyone's "not constructive" meter to go off, as seen from the string of off-topic comments.

Also, Madara's post got a lot of good answers, whereas the answer you got, well... I question whether or not it's really even an answer.

If I were to keep one of them, it would be Madara's simply because of the answers it received.

The takeaway is try to stay focused on the question, as distractions can sometimes be harmful. Is it necessarily fair or right that your question was closed? Maybe. Maybe not. Maybe no one saw how editing might have made a difference. Regardless, I don't think anyone is to blame. Instead, the takeaway is to focus on writing good, neat, fluff-free Q&A that is useful to future visitors.

As an aside, you could still edit your post and clean it up a bit and link it to the other post. Anyone coming from Google who hits your post could still benefit from all the other answers. In this manner, duplicates can actually be helpful, even if your duplicate is the older one. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

Both questions have the same problem:

- They assume pre-ordained knowledge (that using the `mysql_` functions is now inadvisable, without sources (links) to back up that claim.
- They then ask for a list of reasons why they can't use the functions.

I personally would have voted to close both on that grounds, while asking the OP to provide links for the first, and narrow down the sort of 'reasons' they're looking for. I attempted to do this with one edit I made.